# Update iOS app from different project, locked out of sandbox?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

For reasons too convoluted to get into, I had to switch to a completely new project to update an app in the App Store.

Is there anyway to get access to the sandbox of the old app or will the new one just create a completely separate sandbox? In testing my dev builds of the old and new app they are completely different document directories so my archived info doesn't survive the update.

Does going through the app store effect this in any way or am I just out of luck?

I've matched Bundle ID's and provisioning profiles and that hasn't helped anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting the completely new version as an update, the data in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` and `NSLibraryDirectory` will be preserved. If you are creating a new app in iTunes Connect, the data will not be available and there's no way of getting it back (because you can´t access the sandbox of other apps).

To test this, the best thing you can do is to install the old version of the app on your device and run the new one to update it. If you matched the *bundle id* correctly, instead of creating a new app on the *springboard* it should update the existing one. Data **should** be preserved in this update.

Remember to set your *version* number to something higher than before. For example, if your old app is *version 1.0* you should try with *1.1* or *2.0*.

Comment: Turns out capitalization matters in the bundle ID. Thanks, I got it updating correctly